# Don't disable "all" button in range selector in Highstock

Tags: charts, highcharts

In the current version of Highstock (2.0.4), when user (or script) selects all available data using navigator, the "all button" in range selector gets disabled. Is it possible to turn off this behaviour?

It would be great, if the All button could get automatically selected when all data is dispalyed, but simply not disabling it would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is default behaviour, so cannot be changed. Only what you can do is setting "start" state as all.

Ref:
- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.selected

Comment: This makes me sad panda. We are also using setExtremes after rendering, so "selected" doesn't always help. So I'll have to use some ugly hacks - programatically clicking the button instead of calling setExtremes in some cases.

Comment: Any possibility of changing this behaviour so it is at least optional?